# CSS sprite performance and drag and drop

Tags: css, css-sprites

Does anyone know if using a CSS sprite for the background image of a draggable element has and adverse effect on performance - especially on touch enabled devices such as tablets or mobile devices?

Each item is around 50px x 50px and the sprite is 800px x 1400px (20kb)

I just wonder if the browser is working hard to re-position the background image when it's being dragged and re-positioned?

Comment: The overhead of the large image file would probably only incur performance issues during load and decode (the latter occurring when it first comes on screen), so repositioning the element shouldn't have any bearing on this. The easiest way to test your assertion would be with Chrome  dev tools' (F12) timeline tab, recording, and comparing the paint event times during drag.

Answer (score 2):

When you drag an element that has a background position set, the background position is not adjusted, just the element's `left` and `top` values. 800 x 1400 is fairly large for a sprite and even at 20kb, that would be you're only performance issue. Especially on mobile devices.